# Removing unused Windows Roles and Features in Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

Currently Windows Server 2012 uses over 38GBs of disk space. These are SSD drives. Is there a way to remove all the features and roles from disk that I do not need or currently using?

And if I do that can I get them back should I need them.

EDIT: 
Going off the posts below, I could do something like this then?

```
get-windowsFeature | where-object {$_.installed -eq $false} | uninstall-windowsfeature -remove
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dism.exe to remove feature from modern Windows. On 2012, you can use the PowerShell [dism cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852126.aspx):

View features:

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature –Online
```

lets remove one:

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName VolumeActivation-Full-Role -Remove
```

without the -Remove switch you would just disable a feature, with -Remove, the files for the feature are removed from the disk. Using Get-WindowsOptionalFeature again, it now shows:

```
Feature Name : VolumeActivation-Full-Role
State        : DisabledWithPayloadRemoved
```

If you ever decide you need the feature back, you can use another cmdlet:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName xxxx -Source D:\sources
```

You need to specify a source for the files, this could be a local DVD, or network share or a Windows Update server.

Comment: @Frank Thornton - uninstall-windowsfeature is very similar to Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature and you can use both. I would review the feature carefully before removing all unused ones, but you can remove them all in one go.